# scala: Alternative for ClassTag in scala method

Tags: java, scala, reflection

I have a simple method in scala which requires type information of parameters at runtime, thus I am using `ClassTag`, but I want my method to be inter operable with java. But `ClassTag`s are not java friendly. So is there a workaround to make it work with Java?

I want `getElement` method to be interoperable with java.

```
def getElements: Array[SomeType] = ...

def getElement[T <: SomeType : ClassTag](i: Int): T = {
  getElements(i) match {
    case element: T => element
    case element => throw new IllegalArgumentException()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to tell a bit more about what you want to do inside the method. Create arrays? If you really have to, you can use

```
def myMethod[T](x: T): Unit = {
  implicit val classTag = ClassTag[T](x.getClass)
}
```

but of course it will fail if x is null and will cause boxing if x is a primitive type.